# Can't stop flickering on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, flicker, drawimage

I have class that creates a new thread.

`

```
public ScreenG(JPanel PanelR)
{
    Panel = PanelR;
    RenderImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    FPS = 25;
    Hide = false;

    (new Thread() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {   
              while(true)
              {
                  if(Hide == false)
                  {
                    Timer = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000/FPS);

                    if(!DrawRendering)
                    {
                        Graphics g = Panel.getGraphics();
                        g.drawImage(RenderImage, 0, 0, null);
                    }

                    DrawRendering = false;

                    while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= Timer) try { Thread.sleep(1); } catch (InterruptedException e) {Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}
                  }
              }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void draw(BufferedImage ImageR)
{
    DrawRendering = true;
    RenderImage = ImageR;
    Graphics g = Panel.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(RenderImage, 0, 0, null);
}`
```

In my main I create a new instance of ScreenG. This will start a new thread that draws a bufferedImage onto a JPanel with a consistent FPS.
In the main I would then call draw with the image that I created. Sometimes it works but sometimes the image on the panel flickers. I try variations like the draw function taking over the drawing. Non of them work. I could only REDUCE the flickering.

Comment: You should use passive graphics as per the Swing graphics tutorial. Also your code ignores Swing threading rules completely by making key Swing calls in a background thread. I urge you not to do this.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions which are demonstrated in any text book or tutorial. Don't make up your own!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible by design. Swing does not synchronize to the bitmap raster DMA that's actually sending the screen data to your monitor, so it always possible that the screen buffer is read by the DMA while you're busy rendering to it (possible exception is Fullscreen mode).

To at least minimize flickering follow the recommended method of custom Swing painting: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

You can easily trigger periodic repaints on the EDT using a Swing timer, or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait/invokeLater from another thread (whatever works best in your design).

Answer (score 0):

The flickering can be because the rendering isn't fast enough from an update.

Now I do recommend you use `Swing`s `paintComponent (Graphics g)` when rendering its components. That being said. To solve the flickering for you add a `BufferStrategy` in your `JFrame`

Without that code avaible I can only provide a general solution.

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame ();

...

BufferStrategy bufferstrategy = jframe.getBufferStrategy ();

if (bufferstrategy == null) {
    jframe.createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

g.dispose();
bufferstrategy.show();
```

To read more about `BufferStrategy` I recommend a read over at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html).

*Small Note*

There is no reason in your code to either store `JPanel PanelR` or `BufferedImage ImageR`. You can instead directly invoke methods directly on `PanelR` resp. `ImageR`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. I read Oracle tutorial that you recommended and get my paintComponent() function working correctly on the main thread. To do that I am calling JPanel().repaint() from the draw() function. I will learn about using BufferStrategy next.